# how to use session in hyper link selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the code for a link, I want to navigate if and only if the session is not null, how can I do it, please help me...

```
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="Year1Sem1Sub1.aspx" runat="server" align="left" OnClick=(>CIS 11301     Fundamentals of information systems</asp:HyperLink>
    <img src="images/guestPic.jpg" align="right"/>
```

This is my Authentication.ascx code

```
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["loggedUser"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("loginToTheSite.aspx");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to do with the Hyperlink?

Comment: One solution would be-  show the hyperlink only if session is not null and if session is null, don't show the hyperlink at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want to do with the `HyperLink`, but I think I understand what you mean

```
if (Session["loggedUser"] != null)
{
      HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Year1Sem1Sub1.aspx";


      //
      // Or do your response redirect here
      //
}
else
{
      HyperLink1.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not show the Link at all.

```
if(Session["loggedUser"] != null)
{
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="Year1Sem1Sub1.aspx" runat="server" align="left" OnClick=(>CIS 11301     Fundamentals of information systems</asp:HyperLink>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it through jquery also

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="click" CssClass="abc">Click Me</asp:HyperLink>


script type="text/jscript">
    $(".abc").click(function () {
        var session = '<%= Session["login"] %>';
        if (session != "") {
            $(".abc").attr("href", "your url here");
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: The `.ToString()` will fail (NullReferenceException) when that value doesn't exist.